# Using recursion to return the sum of the first n elements of an array arr

Tags: javascript, web, recursion

I'm trying to learn some JavaScript from freecodecamp.org and I stumbled upon a recursion problem which I can't wrap my head around:

Instructions: Write a recursive function, sum(arr, n), that returns the sum of the first n elements of an array arr.

```js
function sum(arr, n) {
  if(n <= 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
  }
}
```

I understand the second part: arr[n -1] adding the item value

But I don't understand what the first part(sum(arr, n-1)) does, and how the arr parameter reacts.

Can anyone help?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: imagine you have an array [1,2,3,4,5] with n = 3
so u call the function with making the stack, by adding arr[n-1], so it 
1 step) + 3
2 step) +2
3 step) +1 
and then u add 0, when n=0

but the first part u don't understand clearly is recalling the function by recursion sum(arr, n - 1), so u call the function decrementing N.

Comment: If you call `sum(arr, 3)` then `sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1]` -> `sum(arr, 2) + arr[2]`. So The sum of the first 3 elements can be calculated as the sum of the first 2 elements plus the value of the third element.

Answer (score 1):

Functional programming is easy to trace because each expression can be replaced with its evaluated result. So when you encounter things like `sum(arr, n - 1)`, fill in `n - 1` and recompute the function.

For example, `sum` the first `5` elements of `arr`

```
sum(arr, 5)
   \
  sum(arr, 4) + arr[4]
     \
    sum(arr, 3) + arr[3]
       \
      sum(arr, 2) + arr[2]
         \
        sum(arr, 1) + arr[1]
           \
          sum(arr, 0) + arr[0]
             \
              0
```

```
sum(arr, 5) = arr[4] + arr[3] + arr[2] + arr[1] + arr[0] + 0
            = 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1
            = 15
```

This works for other problems too, like the classic `fibonacci` algorithm -

```js
function fib(n)
{ if (n < 2)
    return n
  else
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
}
```

```
                                         fib(5)
                             /                           \
                          fib(4)             +           fib(3)        
                     /               \                   /     \
                 fib(3)      +      fib(2)            fib(2) + fib(1) 
                 /     \           /     \            /     \     \      
              fib(2) + fib(1)   fib(1) + fib(0)   fib(1) + fib(0)  1     
              /     \     \      /         \       /          \             
          fib(1) + fib(0)  1    1           0     1            0         
            /         \                                 
           1           0
```

```
fib(5) = 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1
       = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

When executing this code, you create a *stack* composed with *frames*.

Every *frame* is a function call, the number of frames is `n + 1`.

Unrelated: StackOverflow is the name of a common error that happens when the stack size goes beyond a certain limit.

For example, if you pass `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and `4` as parameters, you create implicitly the following *stack* from bottom to top:

```
sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 0) // This resolves first as it doesn't need to call sum again: 0
sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1) // Then this: 0 + 1 = 1
sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 2) // Then this: 1 + 2 = 3
sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3) // Then this: 3 + 3 = 6
sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4) // Then you get the final result: 6 + 4 = 10
```

Answer (score -1):

The part you don't understand is the recursion part actually. With the help of this part your function recalled until n<=0 condition is met. Then it starts to go back until first it's first call.

[image: here's an example of recursion calling]

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your answer so that it can be read on all devices, edited, copied as text, and found through search. As it stands now, your image makes it hard to view and use your answer. See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: It's better to directly address the exact question that is being asked. This is a different problem. Although it's similarly recursive, that won't help the person who asked it.