# How variable decrements work in recursive functions?

Tags: javascript, performance, web, recursion

I want to understand this below recursion. Here `times-1` is passed each time function is called. How it reaches to zero? I mean, when `times-1` is compared by `if(times===1)` then the statments terminates and else is not executed. And how each time decremented value is passed.

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(string, times) {
  if(times < 0) 
    return "";
  if(times === 1) 
    return string;
  else 
    return string + repeatStringNumTimes(string, times - 1);
}
repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3);
```

Comment: it doesnt reach 0 if you pass in a value greater than 0, the first check is probably for when you pass in a value less than 1

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're correct, it doesn't ever run the `return ""` if `times` is greater than 0 for the initial call. This is a safety precaution to avoid blowing the stack if called with 0 or less. BTW, this is OK as a teaching example but is a poor fit for recursion otherwise.

Comment: it can be simplified to `if (times <= 0) return ""; else return string + repeat(string, times - 1)`. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67337190/633183) for additional explanation.